# Getting attributes from features in list of another table using expressions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, list

The goal seems simple, the explanation not, but I try to:

On the one hand, I have a table with several objects ("objects_layer"). On the other hand is a table with a list-field ("list_layer").

I wan't to get the attributes ("prop1", "prop2", "prop3") from all objects in the objects_layer which are written in the "tellmeabout-field" in "list_layer".
I need it as expression or virtual field/layer.

Example:
[image]

The result I expect returns for example as new virtual field in list_layer like this:

[image]

Assume, someone is creating a new entry in "list_layer", and he want's to know the props of A and B as text, so he choose A and B from a list and the expression or virt. field is doing the rest:

[image]

Comment: QGIS 3.10 has an `attributes` function (not present in QGIS LTR 3.4) which may reduce expressions when all fields for a row are queried. Do you need the expression working in QGIS 3.4?

Comment: :-D isn't this the 2rd incarnation of your initial question? Well, this time its a perfect TL;DR...

Comment: A 3.10 solution would be fine!

Comment: @ThingumaBob, in this question a one-to-many relation is involved, and that open the possibility of `get_feature` function use. I think the development of the expression to this question is simpler than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual field with the following expression:

```
array_to_string(
  array_foreach(
    --Replace '{"A","B"}' to 'A,B' and create the array: [ A , B ].
    string_to_array(
      replace(
        "tellmeabout",
        array( '{', '"', '}'),
        array( '', '' , ''))),
    --Then, for each element of the previous array return a string containing:
    array_to_string(
      array_remove_at(
        --All the values of a map created with the attributes of the feature...
        map_avals(
          attributes(
            --from the 'objects_layer' layer, which 'object' value is equal to the...
            get_feature(
              'objects_layer',
              'object',
              --previous element,
              @element))),
        --remove the first value of the map ('fid' value),
        0))),
  --and concatenate the array elements whit a ' / ' character to a string.
  ' / ')
```

*Replace '{"A","B"}' to 'A,B' and create the array: [ A , B ].*
*Then, for each element of the previous array return a string containing:*
*All the values of a map created with the attributes of the feature...*
*from the 'objects_layer' layer, which 'object' value is equal to the...*
*previous element,*
*remove the first value of the map ('fid' value),*
*and concatenate the array elements whit a ' / ' character to a string.*

---

*Notes and references:*

- The previous expression works fine with your sample data in QGIS 3.10. QGIS LTR 3.4 doesn't include the `attributes` function.
- If you plan to arrange *NULL* values, some modifications must be done to handle them.
- Thanks to J. Monticolo for the following answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/343608/133276, which shows the `array_foreach` function.
- Thanks to PieterB for the following answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/343621/133276, which shows the `attributes` function.